# menu visible on all show pages of a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a menu in rails. 
but some parts I only want to see on all the show pages of the projects controller.

I tried :

```
<%unless current_page?(controller : 'projects' , action: 'show' %>
    link1 
    link2 
<% end %>
```

but that would not work because there is no id and I want to get it working on all ids

How to solve this ?

Comment: what do you mean by  _there is no id_? Where are you embedding this, in `layout` or the `#show` view?

Comment: Im using this in layout.html.erb

Comment: and what is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display something for only a specific controller and action, Try This:

```
<% if controller.controller_name == 'controller_name_here' && controller.action_name == 'action_name_here' %>
  .........
<% end %>
```

Or If you want to hide something for only a specific controller and action, Try This:

```
<% if controller.controller_name != 'controller_name_here' && controller.action_name != 'action_name_here' %>
      .........
<% end %>
```

Comment: why `to_s`?  params` are always strings

Comment: @Dimitry_N I'm just used to it.